# How to make onchange work on radio input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have an input field where the value will change automatically when an option is selected. How to write code so that it works the same way when the radio input option is selected?

```js
function changeIncreaseMode() {
  let selectMode = $("#selectMode").val();
  let multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();
  
  if(selectMode == 'usingMultiplier'){
    var increase = (multiplier/100) + 1;
  } else {
    var increase = (multiplier - 1) * 100;
  }

  $("#multiplier").val(parseFloat(increase).toFixed(2));  
        
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="multiplier">Increase on loss:</label> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="multiplier" value="2" placeholder="Enter multiplier" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,8})?$" required />
      <select id="selectMode" onchange="changeIncreaseMode();">
        <option value="usingMultiplier">X</option>
        <option value="usingPercentage">%</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <!-- increase using multiplier or percentage -->
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline small">
      <input type="radio" id="usingMultiplier" name="usingMultiplier" class="custom-control-input" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="usingMultiplier">using multiplier <i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline small">
      <input type="radio" id="usingPercentage" name="usingMultiplier" class="custom-control-input">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="usingPercentage">using percentage <i class="fas fa-percentage"></i></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end increase using multiplier or percentage -->
    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

and then i have also prepared a code that will calculate and display the results when the submit button is clicked. the code snippet looks like this :

```
base_bet = multiplier * base_bet; //increase loss using multiplier/first-code

base_bet = multiplier / 100 * base_bet + base_bet; //increase loss using percentage/second-code
```

How to make when selected the first option then the calculation uses the first code, if selected the second option then the calculation uses the second code?

I'm very grateful before and after.

Comment: What should happen if the user selects the first option of the `<select>` (multiplier) `"X"`, and the second radio input "using percentage"? Do you really need two means to (apparently) make one choice? It *can* be made to work, but it seems an unnecessary user-interface friction (without knowing the rationale of this - probably-simplified - demo).

Comment: If the user selects the first option then the increase will use multiplication, if the second option increase using the percentage. as in the code sample, the value "2" will change to "100" when selecting the second option "%".
It works in the "select" option, but I need it to work also in the "input radio"

Comment: So the choice in the radio buttons should be the same as the choice made in the `<select>`?

Comment: yes that's right, the option "using multiplier" on the radio represents the "x" in the <select>
the selection on the radio "using percentage" will represent the "%" in the <select>.
so if <select> is removed, the radio button will work like <select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will be pleasure if this code can help you.

```js
function changeIncreaseMode() {
  let selectMode = $("#selectMode").val();
  let multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();
  
  if(selectMode == 'usingMultiplier'){
    var increase = (multiplier/100) + 1;
  } else {
    var increase = (multiplier - 1) * 100;
  }

  $("#multiplier").val(parseFloat(increase).toFixed(2));    
}

function changeIncreaseModeByRadio() {
  const isMultiplier = $("#usingMultiplier").is(':checked');
  const isPercentage = $("#usingPercentage").is(':checked');
  const multiplier = $("#multiplier").val();
  
  let increase = 0;
  if(isMultiplier){
    increase = (multiplier/100) + 1;
  }
  else if(isPercentage){
    increase = (multiplier - 1) * 100;
  }

  $("#multiplier").val(parseFloat(increase).toFixed(2));    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="multiplier">Increase on loss:</label> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="multiplier" value="2" placeholder="Enter multiplier" pattern="^\d*(\.\d{0,8})?$" required />
      <select id="selectMode" onchange="changeIncreaseMode();">
        <option value="usingMultiplier">X</option>
        <option value="usingPercentage">%</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    
    <!-- increase using multiplier or percentage -->
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline small">
      <input type="radio" id="usingMultiplier" name="usingMultiplier" class="custom-control-input" onChange="changeIncreaseModeByRadio();" checked>
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="usingMultiplier">using multiplier <i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio custom-control-inline small">
      <input type="radio" id="usingPercentage" name="usingMultiplier" class="custom-control-input" onChange="changeIncreaseModeByRadio();">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="usingPercentage">using percentage <i class="fas fa-percentage"></i></label>
    </div>
    <!-- end increase using multiplier or percentage -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I've tried it, but maybe there's a little mistake on my part, I hope that when the radio is selected then the results that come out in the "Increase on loss:" field are the same as the results when selecting on <select>.

Option "using multiplier" on the radio represents the "x" in the <select> the selection on the radio "using percentage" will represent the "%" in the <select>. so if <select> is removed, the radio button will work like <select>

Comment: I updated the code.
But you wrote this calculation way in the question.
base_bet = multiplier * base_bet; //increase loss using multiplier/first-code
base_bet = multiplier / 100 * base_bet + base_bet; //increase loss using percentage/second-code
So I applied this way, is it wrong?

Comment: Thanks you saved my time, sorry for my messy writing. the code you wrote is working fine, I would just remove the <select> command and use only radio options.

While for the calculation code I mean placed in a different place.
base_bet = multiplier * base_bet; //increase loss using multiplier(first-code).

base_bet = multiplier / 100 * base_bet + base_bet; //increase loss using percentage(second-code).

so how to make it somewhere else if radio option "using multiplier" calculation using (first-code). if the radio option is "using percentage" the calculation uses (second-code).